# viewDidLoad of an unrelated UIViewController is getting called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

While debugging a problem, I noticed that when changing orientation, the `viewDidLoad` of an unrelated `UIViewController` is getting called.

It appears to be unrelated to my problem, but it's totally weird.

This `UIViewController` is accessible only from the `UITabBar` (in the storyboard itself)

Comment: Try to debug by placing the breakpoints in the view did load that is calling.

Comment: If iOS 8, look at the view controller hierarchy by running app from Xcode, hitting pause button, and at the `(lldb)` prompt type `po [UIViewController _printHierarchy]`. I wonder if your "unrelated" view controller is in the hierarchy for some reason.

Comment: @Rob - hmm.. `MainTabBarViewController` has all the TabBar viewControllers under it. I'm guessing it calls `ViewDidLoad`. If you like to submit it as an answer... Loved the _printHierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If testing this on iOS 8, you can look at the view controller hierarchy by running the app, pausing execution by hitting the "pause" button:

[image: pause]

Then, at the `(lldb)` prompt, enter the command

```
po [UIViewController _printHierarchy]
```

This can identify which view controllers are in the view hierarchy.